# Query to get Daywise on the month selected

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access database table datetime column. When I select a particular month (say, July), I have to get datewise data in that month.

The output should appear in the same format as the attached image.

Every Employee who comes in on a particular date should display “P” for that day.  If the Employee doesn’t come in on a particular day (like Sat or Sun), then I have to display “WO” for that day.

When an Employee has not come in (like Sat or Sun), then there is no entry in the log table for that date.

How could an Access query be written to obtain this output?  I am using an MS Access 2003 database.

Edit: we have to use TRANSFORM and PIVOT, but the issue is when an employee is not available (Sat, Sun) we still need to show data in the output.

---

[image][image]

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: please describe more by providing some example, table structure is needed

Comment: Is it viable for a C# solution? You have tagged C# but asking for a SQL solution?

Comment: @ unlimit : table has been attached.

Comment: @Chee mun Low: please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a query that reads EmpID and CheckTime from the first table, and adds one additional column:

```
DateWise: IIf(Weekday([CheckTime])=1 Or Weekday([CheckTime])=7,"WO","P")
```

You will need an additional table with every date of the year in it (we'll call it YearDates).  Left join that table to your query like so:

```
Select YD.YearDates, Q2.* from YearDates YD LEFT JOIN Query2 Q2 ON YD.YearDates = DATEVALUE(Q2.CheckTime)
```

The DATEVALUE will strip the time off your dates in CheckTime so they will match date against date.